# Python: How to format series of images to all fit on A4 page?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on an art project and am converting text to binary to images.
So far, I have what I think is the hard part done and am almost there ...
except i'm not quite sure how to approach this last bit of the problem:

I have a series of images displayed one after another but I need to wrap the images so that they are formatted to all fit on a page of A4 (printer paper) in landscape orientation.
How should I approach this?

I have the basic script to convert text to binary to images.

One additional issue I'm seeing is that when I run the script on the entire passage, too many files are opened and I receive an error(shown below):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ascii_to_binary.py", line 73, in <module>
imgs = [Image.open(i) for i in list_im]     
File "/home/odroid/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2410, in open
fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
IOError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'open_circle.png'
```

Here's the script in its entirety for reference:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import imutils
import sys
from PIL import Image

open_circle = 'open_circle.png'
closed_circle = 'closed_circle.png'
diamond = 'diamond.png'

text1 = open("filename.text", "r")
letters = text1.read()

a = len(letters)


binary_text = [None]*a #pre-allocating a list

encoded_bin = ' '.join([bin(ord(letter))[2:].zfill(8) for letter in letters])       

b = len(encoded_bin[0:18])

list_im = [0]*b

for val in range(b):
    if encoded_bin[val] == '0':
        list_im[val] = closed_circle
    if encoded_bin[val] == '1':
        list_im[val] = open_circle  
    if encoded_bin[val] == ' ':
        list_im[val] = diamond

imgs = [Image.open(i) for i in list_im]     

min_shape = sorted( [(np.sum(i.size), i.size) for i in imgs] )[0][1]
imgs_comb = np.hstack( (np.asarray(i.resize(min_shape)) for i in imgs) )        

imgs_comb = Image.fromarray(imgs_comb)
imgs_comb.show()
```